# Spring Boot SSEEmitter send HttpStatus.ok when its done

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have some service method which is executing for 3 seconds. I would like to send information to the client when processing starts (HTTPStatus.PROCESSING), and after (3 seconds) when its done(HTTPSTATUS.OK). Now i have this. Can't realize how to improove. It doesn't work correctly

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    private ExecutorService nonBlockingService = Executors
            .newCachedThreadPool();


 @Async
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/sse")
    public SseEmitter handleSse() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
        emitter.send(HttpStatus.PROCESSING);
        TestService.doSMG();
        emitter.send(HttpStatus.OK);
        return emitter;
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public class TestService {
    public static void doSMG() throws InterruptedException {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var sse = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/sse');
sse.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var el = document.getElementById('sse');
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(evt.data));
    el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id = "sse">
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to return the `SseEmitter` and pass it to the `TestService.doMSMG` message so that when that is finished it can send the message. Or execute the `TestService.doSMG()` method async and afterwards send themessage. Currently it does everything directly. Also remember, the emitter stays open, so after sending the last message you also need to call the `complete` method on it so it can do cleanup.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your answer. can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is fully sequential which means it executes everything in order. You should return the `SseEmitter` as soon as possible and run everything else in a background thread.

To run things in a background thread you want to inject a `TaskExecutor` or even better an `AsyncTaskExecutor` so you can submit tasks to it for later execution (as soon there is a thread available for processing).

This would look something like this

```java
@RestController
public class MainController {

  private final AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
  
  public MainController(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    this.tashExecutor=taskExecutor;
  }  

  @CrossOrigin
  @GetMapping("/sse")
  public SseEmitter handleSse() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();
    taskExecutor.submit(() -> {
        emitter.send(HttpStatus.PROCESSING);
        TestService.doSMG();
        emitter.send(HttpStatus.OK);
    });
    return emitter;
  }
}
```

This will execute the task in the background, while immediatly returning the `SseEmitter`.